# if else with linked image

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a very simple one but been struggling a bit with it.

```
if (getCookie("Account")=="True"){ ... } else { ... }
```

I would like to add in the brackets of the if and else a linked image banner. One image if they have a account and another if they do not.

True

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="/images/imageTrue.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Else

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="/images/imageElse.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Thank You for any help

Comment: Please add better title of your question

Comment: we appreciate that you want to finish your homework or what. but then dude, please try to learn something. this is something a 3rd grader can do. you know the answer to your problem. do it!

Comment: Have a read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Semi-Friends Thanks for the reply. I hope you have a great day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```js
if (getCookie("Account")=="True"){ 
  $('#img').attr('src', '/images/imageTrue.jpg');
} else { 
  $('#img').attr('src', '/images/imageFalse.jpg');
}

// your getCookie function
function getCookie(){
   return Math.random()*2>1?"True":"False";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img id="img" src="/images/imageTrue.jpg" alt="" />click me</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried at least ?
To change the source of the image, select the image with jQuery with something like that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#id') // to select an id
     $('.class') // to select a class
     $('a') // to select all <a> tags
});
```

Then change the source and alt of image with attr function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if (getCookie("Account")=="True"){ 
         $('a').attr('href','http://example.com/');
         $('img').attr({'src':'img/my-img-1.jpg', 'alt':'My alt'});
     } else { 
         $('a').attr('href','http://example.com/');
         $('img').attr({'src':'img/my-img-2.jpg', 'alt':'My alt'});
     }
});
```

Here to help you : http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

you can set this by accessing the element first and then set the src attribute with link.
Ex:

```
var el=$('#id');
if (getCookie("Account")=="True"){
    el.attr('src','/images/imageTrue.jpg');
}
else {
    el.attr('src','/images/imageFalse.jpg');
}
```